# Button not resolving symbol

Tags: java, android

I wrote a very simple activity in which when a button is pressed it changes to another one. But it seems to be unable to resolve symbol on line 24, the second setOnClickListener and I am honestly pulling my hairs here. Its not the same, because the code should work.

```
package com.example.example.ramdomjokes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView JokeText;
    Jokes jokeHolder = new Jokes();
    Button btncat;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        JokeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JokeText);

        btncat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btncat.setOnClickListener(new View.setOnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View view){
               Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cats.class);
               startActivity(i);
           }

       } );

    }


    public void genJoke(View view)
    {
        JokeText.setText(jokeHolder.nextJoke());

    }



}
```

Comment: It is `View.OnClickListener` not `View.setOnClickListener`.

Comment: I love you man, like I really do.